# how to run ruby app on startup

Tags: linux, ruby

I'm trying to run a sinatra app on startup in linux mint. I'm using the startup applications preferences to add the path to the ruby file that I'm trying to execute:

```
shotgun /path/to/file/file.rb
```

This is able to execute the file. But when I access http://my.dev:9393 which is the address where shotgun is serving the sinatra app it gives me this error:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the app runs under user that does not have proper ruby gems installed.